# Factor-level calculations

Tags: r, categorical-data, factors

I have created this dummy data set, below, to look similar to the actual data I am working on.

```
library(tidyverse)
factor <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I")
year <- c("2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020")
sales <- c(5, 4, 2, 1, 6, 4, 7, 8, 5, 1, 6, 7, 2, 4, 1, 6, 7, 5)

df <- tibble(factor, year, sales) 
df

# A tibble: 18 x 3
   factor year  sales
   <chr>  <chr> <dbl>
 1 A      2019      5
 2 B      2019      4
 3 C      2019      2
 4 D      2019      1
 5 E      2019      6
 6 F      2019      4
 7 G      2020      7
 8 H      2020      8
 9 I      2020      5
10 A      2020      1
```

I would like to perform mathematical operations on the sales column for each and every factor. So, for example, %_change(factor_A) = sales_2020/sales_2019, %_change(factor_B) = sales_2020/sales_2019, and so on. In my actual dataset, any given factor can show up any number of times for any given year.

Given that each factor can show up multiple times for any given year, I am aware that I might need to group by the factors and years (even though they only show once per year in my example). So:

```
df %>%
  group_by(factor, year) %>%
  summarise(
    n = sum(sales) # this is to account for factors showing up multiple times within the same year
  )
```

I know that I can pivot wider, so that each year has its own column, perform the maths 'horizontally', and then pivot back to long but I would like to know if there is a more elegant solution, perhaps by looping through the factors.

I hope someone can advise me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do. `group_by` factor, and then compare for each factor the (total summed) value of `sales` for year 2020 with the (total) value of `sales` for year 2019.

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(factor) %>% 
  mutate(pct_change = sum(sales[year == "2020"]) / sum(sales[year == "2019"]))
```

output

```r
# A tibble: 18 × 4
# Groups:   factor [9]
   factor year  sales pct_change
   <chr>  <chr> <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 A      2019      5      0.2  
 2 B      2019      4      1.5  
 3 C      2019      2      3.5  
 4 D      2019      1      2    
 5 E      2019      6      0.667
 6 F      2019      4      0.25 
 7 G      2019      7      0.857
 8 H      2019      8      0.875
 9 I      2019      5      1    
10 A      2020      1      0.2  
11 B      2020      6      1.5  
12 C      2020      7      3.5  
13 D      2020      2      2    
14 E      2020      4      0.667
15 F      2020      1      0.25 
16 G      2020      6      0.857
17 H      2020      7      0.875
18 I      2020      5      1
```

I slightly changed your data because some of the factors did not have two time points:

```r
library(tidyverse)
factor <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I")
year <- c("2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020")
sales <- c(5, 4, 2, 1, 6, 4, 7, 8, 5, 1, 6, 7, 2, 4, 1, 6, 7, 5)

df <- tibble(factor, year, sales) 
df
```

Comment: If there are multiple entries per factor-year, should it be `sum(sales[year..` ?